# std::bit_cast vs reinterpret_cast in file I/O

Tags: c++, file-io, c++20, reinterpret-cast, bit-cast

How should one cast pointers to `char*`/`const char*`? Using `reinterpret_cast`? Or probably `std::bit_cast`?

A simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bit>


int main( )
{
    std::uint32_t var { 301 };

    {
    std::ofstream file { "myfile.bin" };
    file.write( std::bit_cast<const char*>( &var ), sizeof( var ) );
    }

    std::uint32_t var2 { 10 };

    {
    std::ifstream file { "myfile.bin" };
    file.read( std::bit_cast<char*>( &var2 ), sizeof( var2 ) );
    }
    std::cout << var2 << '\n';
}
```

This seems to works fine. Also replacing all the `std::bit_cast`s with `reinterpret_cast`s works fine too.

So which one is more correct in this case? And what about using `std::byte*` instead of `char*` for file I/O (though I tried it and it did not compile)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, of course all of this only applies if `var` and `var2` have the same type and this type is trivially-copyable. A very common mistake is to try to `write` and `read` non-trivially-copyable types like `std::string` in this way, which is fundamentally wrong.

---

`std::bit_cast` is not generally safe, because there is no guarantee that `const char*` and `std::uint32_t*` use the same representation for the pointer values. They technically don't even need to have the same size. Whether you are going to come into contact with a platform where this is the case, is a different question.

The intended purpose of `std::bit_cast` is to reinterpret the object representation of one value of a given type into another type, giving you a (possibly different) corresponding value of the target type. (For example if you know the representation used for `float` and `int`, both of them are the same size and you have an integer value from which you want to retrieve a `float` value corresponding to the same representation.)

For pointers this is usually not really what you want. You want the value of the pointer to be preserved (or to get a pointer value to a related object or the object representation). How the representations of the original and converted pointer value relate is secondary.

`reinterpret_cast` does the above. `reinterpret_cast<const char*>` is the standard approach and is almost as correct as you can get. There are some defects in the standard regarding how exactly the result of this cast can be used, but for practical purposes you can just assume that it will always give you a pointer to the first element of the object representation (interpreted as a `char` array), which is what you want `write` to write to the file.

The same applies to the `read` case (except that `const` can not be used on reads for obvious reasons; `const` isn't required for the `write` case either, but shows intent more clearly).

---

If you want a to stay completely in the realm of what the standard currently specifies, I think the following should be fine (except for missing error and end-of-file checking, which could incur undefined behavior):

```
int main( )
{
    std::uint32_t var { 301 };

    {
    std::ofstream file { "myfile.bin" };
    char buf[sizeof(var)]{};
    std::memcpy(buf, &var, sizeof(var));
    file.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }

    std::uint32_t var2 { 10 };

    {
    std::ifstream file { "myfile.bin" };
    char buf[sizeof(var2)]{};
    file.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
    std::memcpy(&var2, buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
    std::cout << var2 << '\n';
}
```

But practically, any compiler will have the expected behavior with `reinterpret_cast`, so there isn't much of a point to this.

---

If you were to design the file IO operations nowadays, you would probably use `std::byte` instead of `char` in the interface, but `std::byte` has been introduced only with C++17 while `iostream` has been around since (before) C++98. You can't convert a `std::byte*` to a `const*` without another `reinterpret_cast`, so it is pointless to go through it.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `bit_cast` is mend to cast values between types of the same size, e.g. float to uint32_t, not for pointers.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I added some (somwhat clumsy) explanation. I might revise it later.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. So I guess I might stick to `reinterpret_cast` since there is not much benefit in in using `bit_cast` on pointers. I thought that it was safer to cast using `bit_cast` but seems like that's not the case here.

Comment: @digito_evo Yes, this is one of the rare cases where `reinterpret_cast` is the right tool.